# Cards picking probability question at poker 1 to 10

Tags: probability, card-games

My question is about a version of poker I heard of, it goes like this:
you have cards from 1 to 10, each card is only twice in the deck, each round a card is picked for you and for your opponent, you can only see his card, and he can only see you're card, you can raise the bet on your turn, fold or equal to your opponent bet, another important rule is that if you fold with a card of 10 that you got(and of course you do not suppose to be aware of), you will lose 10 chips.

given a card of you're opponent and the current cards left in the stack, how can I calculate If I should bet, fold, or equal? I want to create some function...

I forgot most of what I learned years ago in probability so help is needed here, thanks!